# filtering out based on tag value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I am using BeautifulSoup to do some web scraping and part of the result looks like this:

```
...
<tr>
    <th> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 1]'> </a></th>
    ...
    ...
    <td> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 2]'> </a></td>
</tr>,
<tr>
    <th> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 1]'> </a></th>
    ...
    ...
    <td> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 3]'> </a></td>
</tr>,
<tr>
    <th> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 1]'> </a></th>
    ...
    ...
    <td> class = "[whatever]" </td>
</tr>,
...
```

Everything about the three tr blocks is structurally the same, except the fact that the third one doesn't have an "a href = [something]" tag in the end. How do I get to filter that last block out? I tried to do it on the basis of length, but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit: my intended result is something like this:

```
...
<tr>
    <th> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 1]'> </a></th>
    ...
    ...
    <td> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 2]'> </a></td>
</tr>,
<tr>
    <th> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 1]'> </a></th>
    ...
    ...
    <td> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 3]'> </a></td>
</tr>,
...
```

Comment: html parser for python?

Comment: try parsing based on <td> and </td>  (or <th> etc... )then if href exists you can work based on that.

Comment: "I tried to do it on the basis of length" great, share that code you tried and someone will be more likely to provide a proper answer.

Comment: What's the expected output? The `href` or everything else besides that?

Comment: Apologies for the issues. I've edited the post to include my wanted output.

Comment: So you want to alter the html rather than extract the values from it?

Comment: I would maybe add more detail to the title, e.g. "filter parent tag based on presence of nested, child tag"

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to remove all `th` and `td` tags if they don't contain any `a` tags. If so, you can [iterate](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) all `th` and `td` tags and [`decompose`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) all which don't have `a` tags as direct [children](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children). Like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


text = """
<tr>
    <th> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 1]'> </a></th>
    ...
    ...
    <td> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 2]'> </a></td>
</tr>,
<tr>
    <th> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 1]'> </a></th>
    ...
    ...
    <td> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 3]'> </a></td>
</tr>,
<tr>
    <th> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 1]'> </a></th>
    ...
    ...
    <td> class = "[whatever]" </td>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features='lxml')
for item in soup.find_all(["th", "td"]):
    if len([c for c in item.children if c.name == 'a']) == 0:
        item.decompose()
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to filter the `tr` blocks to only return the two in which the `td` tag contains an `a` tag with an `href` (doesn't matter if the `th` tag has an `a` tag). As of BeautifulSoup4.7+, you can use CSS selectors to accomplish this quite elegantly:

```
text = """<tr>
    <th> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 1]'> </a></th>
    ...
    ...
    <td> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 2]'> </a></td>
</tr>,
<tr>
    <th> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 1]'> </a></th>
    ...
    ...
    <td> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 3]'> </a></td>
</tr>,
<tr>
    <th> class = "[whatever]" <a href = '[link 1]'> </a></th>
    ...
    ...
    <td> class = "[whatever]" </td>
</tr>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
soup.select('tr:has(> td > a)')
```

Output:

[image]

This was the only method I could get to work, but I'd appreciate any other answers that use a different approach, e.g. using `soup.find_all('tr', ...)` with correct parameters.